# Jump to Footer On Scroll - Woocommerce Pages Phones Only

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mobile

***FIXED: ADD     overflow-anchor: none; to .wooCommerce ul.product

When I load any Woocommerce product or category page on my site, https://www.cecilyskincare.com, and scroll up over the last two products, my page jumps to the footer. I have researched for a while and can't find any solution. I apologize if this has been covered elsewhere. If someone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is a link where it happens:
https://www.cecilyskincare.com/product/olive-dual-cleansing-oil/

https://www.cecilyskincare.com/product-category/cleansers/

Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess it's the 'scroll to top' script in your theme. Can you try turning that off to see if it fixes it?

Comment: I viewed the linked site and could not reproduce the problem

Comment: Thank you @Rup unfortunately turning off the 'To Top' button didn't work. It doesn't happen on any of the pages that are just simple Elementor pages (no woocommerce). It only happens on the woocommerce pages. It is odd.

Comment: I just found out that this only happens on Android, not on iPhone.

Comment: ***FIXED: ADD     overflow-anchor: none; to .wooCommerce ul.product